# How do you remove a stubbornly stuck rear hub on a 1993 Honda fourtrax 300?

Tags: honda, brakes, atv

[image]I have a Honda Fourtrax and I have tried numerous things to get this stubborn hub off the rear axle it just won't budge I am open to any idea short of a stick of dynamite.

Comment: It would be helpful if you listed the things you have tried.

Comment: Presumably you are trying to pull the hub off the splines, is that right?

Comment: Did you try using a three-jaw/four-jaw puller?

Comment: Yes I did I even used a hydrolic 3 jaw puller yes I am trying to pull the hub off the splines I have tried heating it I have tried beating it with a sledge hammer I have tried greaseing the hell out of this thing this is the first time I have ever run into this problem the hub usually just slides off I am so frustrated with this thing

Comment: A picture could be worth a thousand words here.

Comment: I once used a slide hammer attached to a puller to remove a particularly stubborn hub. Took about 20 minutes of continuous hammering.

Comment: As u can see in picture used heat there is a 3 jaw hydraulic puller sledge hammer and pry bars help and I broke my other 3 jaw hammer puller fighting this thing

Comment: Unfortunately, twice in my life, I've been involved in similar situations where we ultimately gave up, pulled the axle, and replaced the axle and hub both.  One time was a hurry, so we did it after only a couple hours of trying, the other was a decision made after working on the car a few hours here and there across several months...

Comment: Oh and I have used an air hammer

Comment: I know you have tried a hydraulic puller, but do you have a normal one that you can tighten then strike the end, sometimes the shock in line with the shaft makes a difference.

Comment: Just wanting to confirm, your model is the TRX300EX and not the TRX300 for the TRX300FW.  The TRX300 is a shaft driven but I can't see the center of the axle to determine.  There's a big difference between the different models.  As well, if memory serves me there is a circlip that requires removal, did you find and remove that bad boy?

Answer (score 2):

Heat is the right way to go here, but did you heat the hub until it was cherry red? When I say red I mean RED (as in glowing), not just hot. It's about the only way you are going to get it off. It really needs to be completely hot all the way around so the bond between the hub and the axle will be broken. You'll probably only be beating your head against the concrete until you do, then it still may not work. In that case @BrianKnoblauch is right, replacement of the entire axle may be the only recourse.

Answer (score 2):

This is on old post but hopefully someone stumbles upon it that can help. The only way I've been able to get very stubborn ones off is to make a puller. Sometimes you can have luck removing the axle nut, putting the wheel back on, and using a three jaw puller through the wheel if it has holes big enough for the jaws. If not, I made my own puller. Big piece of plate steel with a 1" hole in the middle, and two holes drilled diagonally that match up with the lug stud locations. Then, stick a regular flywheel puller, or center puller in between your flat plate and the hub, with the wrench side sticking out the center hole of your plate of course. Thread the lugs on half way, with metric bolts going through your plate using the other 1/2 of the threads, and crank that bastard off. I've always gotten them off this way. Heat the crap out of the spline area of the hub and shoot some lube on the splines as you crank to avoid killing the hub.